# Find all previous Tuesdays in a given range?

Tags: java, android

What I need to do in my Android project is to find all the previous Tuesdays for the last three months and put them into a String Array. It appears that neither the `Calendar Class` nor `SimpleDateFormat` would work for this.

So for example, today is Tuesday, so it would start today and I'd need to return 2013_8_13, and next in the array would be 2013_8_6, then 2013_7_30, and so on. Am I wrong about the `Calendar Class` or `SimpleDateFormat`? If so, could you give me an idea as to how it could be done?

Comment: Start at the current day. calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); till you find a Tuesday. When you find it, calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7); until you go back 3 months of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated answer to go back to a certain day instead of back a certain number of days. Also changed String array to ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> tuesdayArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_M_d");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Date date = new Date();

Date cutoffDate;
int cutoffYear = 2013;
int cutoffMonth = Calendar.JUNE;
int cutoffDayOfMonth = 25;
cutoffDate = new GregorianCalendar(cutoffYear, cutoffMonth, cutoffDayOfMonth).getTime();

while (day != Calendar.TUESDAY) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}

int i = 0;
while (date.after(cutoffDate)) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth).getTime();
    tuesdayArrayList.add(dateFormat.format(date));
    Log.d("myTag: ", tuesdayArrayList.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Wow, Adam very cool! Now all I have to do is pop it into my list adapter.

Comment: Adam, your solution works great! Is there a way to modify it so that it doesn't go back a certain number of days (-90), but rather goes back to a certain date, 2013_6_25 ? Is that possible?

Comment: Never mind, Adam, I fixed it so it goes back to 2013_6_25. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer. Also changed String array to an ArrayList so there is no set limit to keep.

Comment: Adam, how did you know I was trying to figure out how to make it an ArrayList? Thanks so much!